# Struggling to understand proofs involving modules.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Currently, I am faced with solving the following proof(s).

Lemma 1: If n ≡ 3 mod 4 then n has a prime divisor p for which p ≡ 3 mod 4.

Lemma 2: If p ≡ 3 mod 4 then p cannot divide n and n + 2 for any n.

Lemma 3: If p_1...p_k are all primes congruent to 3 mod 4 then N = p_1^2 * p_2^2....p_k^2 is congruent to 1 mod 4.

Theorem: There are infinitely many primes congruent to 3 mod 4.

***I am not looking for direct answers, this is something I wish to be able to understand better and solve on my own.***

Although I am struggling to understand what it means for n ≡ 3 mod 4. On top of that concept, I also don't quite understand the following statement: n ≡ 3 mod 4 means 4 | n - 3, so there exists a k such that n - 3 = 4k.

The big concepts I think I'm failing to understand properly are congruence and congruence classes. So anything having to do with the following notation: "≡".

The help is much appreciated!

Comment: The numbers with $n\equiv3\pmod 4$ are $3$, $7$, $11$, $15$, $19$, $23$, $27$, $31$, $35$, etc. Lemma 1 states that each number in this list has a prime factor within the same list.

Comment: By definition $n\equiv 3\bmod 4$ means $4\mid n-3$, and this, by definition, means that there exists a $k$ such that $n-3=4k$. So if you say "also don't quite understand the following statement", then you just have to review the definitions of $a \equiv b \bmod m$ and $a \mid b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $a \equiv b \pmod n$ means "$a$ and $b$ have a relationship with each other".  And the relationship the have in common is:  If you consider integers by whether they are or are not divisible by $n$ and if they are not divisible by $n$ the by what "offset" their remainders are, then $a$ and $b$ are both such "divisible by $n$" characteristic.

In other words  $a \equiv b \pmod n$ means each of the following

i) $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.  That is  $a = r + n*k$ for some integer $k$ and $0 \le r < n$ and $b = r + n*j$ for some integer $j$ and the *exact* same $r$.

ii) $a = b + m*n$ for some integer $m$. This is the *exact* same statement as i) because if $a = r + n*k$ and $b = r + n*j$ then $a = b + n*(k-j)=b + n*m$ for $m = k-j$.

iii) $n$ divides $a-b$ evenly.  This is the *exact* same statement as i) and ii) because if $a = r + n*k$ and $b = r + n*j$ and $a = b + n*m$ then $a-b = n*(k -j)=n*m$ and $n$ divides into $a-b$ evenly.

So

$n \equiv 3\pmod 4$ *means* by definition that there is an integer $k$ so that $n = 3+ 4k$.  If $k = ..... -2, -1, 0, 1,2,3,4, .....$ then $n = ..... -5, -1, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, .....$.  And that means $n-3 = ..... -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ....$ and that $4|n-3$ because $4$ *does* divide $...... -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16,, ...$ and $\frac {n-3}4$ is the integer $...... -2, -1, 0, ,1, 2, 3, 4,.....$

So $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ means

i).  That when $n$ is divide by $4$ the remainder will be $3$.

ii).  That $n = 3 + 4k$ for some integer $k$.

iii).  Then $\frac {n-3}4= k$ for some integer $k$.

iv) That $n \in \{....., -8, -5, -1, 3, 7, 1, 15, 19, ....\}$.

Those four statements are *exactly* the same.

So...

So lemma 1:

If $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then it has a prime divisor of the form $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

That means if $n$ is number of the form $n = 3 + 4k$ (for example:  $55 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ because $55 = 3 + 13*4$) then it will also have a prime factor of the form $p = 3+4j$. And, indeed, the prime factors of $55$ are $5$ and $11$ and $11 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ because $11 = 3 + 4*2$.

Okay, to prove it:

One:  $n$ must have prime divisors.

Two: If $p$ is a prime divisor then $p$ when divided by $4$ must have a remainder.  It could be that the remainder would be $0, 1,2$ or $3$.  In other words *exactly* one of the following is true:  $p \equiv 0\pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ or $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  (This is true for *any* integer.)

Three: if $p\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ then $p = 0 + 4k$ for some integer $k$ so $p = 4k$.  This is impossible because $p$ is prime.

if $p\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ then $p = 2 + 4k$ for some integer $k$.  So $p$ is even.  But $p$ is prime  and $2$ is the only even prime so $p = 2$.  But $n\equiv 3 \mod 4$ so $n = 3 + 4m$ for some $m$ so $n$ is odd.  So $p \ne 2$.  So this is impossible.

So there are only two possible options.  $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 3 \pmod  4$.

Four If $n$ has *NO* prime factors so that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then that would mean that *ALL* of the prime factors of $n$ would all be so that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Prove that that is impossible.

Hint:  If $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ then $a = 1 + 4k$ and $b = 1 + 4j$ for some $j$ and $k$.  So $ab = (1+4k)(1 + 4j) = 1 + 4k + 4j + 16jk$.  So $ab \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This explanation is really appreciated and I will be sure to read it over multiple times before applying this to my current work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE Aleksei. Nice question!

Okay first, what does $n\equiv 3\mod 4$ mean?

You might remember from your early education be taught division using remainders.

For instance: "$7 \text{ divided by } 2 \text{ is } 3 \text{ remainder } 1$".
This is because $7=(1\times 4) +3$

Mod notation works very similarly to this, we say that $n\equiv  3\mod 4$ if:
$$n \text{ divided by } 4 \text{ is something remainder } 3$$

If we call the 'something' $k$, then we have $n=4k+3$ (use my number example if you don't see how).

You can rearrange that statement to see the other equalities.

$4 | (n-3)$ means $4 \text{ divides } (n-3)$, so for example $4|8$ is true because $4$ is a factor of $8$.

The use of the $\equiv$ symbol as opposed to the $=$ I don't understand personally, but it's the common notation.

### Now for the Lemmas:

The first one states that every $n$ that meets $n=4k+3$ (for integer $k$) has a prime factor $p=4q+3$ (for integer $q$). If $n$ is prime, this is trivial, as $n=p$

To prove this Lemma, note that any odd number is of either the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ (for integer $k$) and that a non-prime odd number has two odd factors. You should be able to take it from there.

---

The second one states that $\frac{n(n+2)}{4k+3}$ *cannot* be an integer. My hint to you is that since $n(n+2)$ is even, and $4k+3$ is odd, the result of this division must be *even*.

---

The third one states that for:
$$p_r=4k_r+3$$
$$p_1^2\cdot p_2^2\cdot...\cdot p_n^2=4t+1$$
Notice: $$(4k_r+3)(4k_r+3)=16k_r^2+24k_r+9=4(4k_r^2+6k_r+2)+1$$ which is of the form $4a_r+1$. So the expression becomes:

$$(4a_1+1)(4a_2+1)(...)(4a_n+1)$$

---

For the theorem, just assume there is a maximum prime $P$, and then show a bigger one can be made using it.

Hint: $(4a+3)(4b+3)(4c+3)=4d+3$ $(\text{for }a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Z)$

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the help, it is sad that I can only rate 1 person answer as the best answer but your feedback is just as important to me as the one above. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me and hopefully I won't have to ask any more future questions for this problem but we will see about that, I am always struggling when it comes to discrete mathematics but it is so crucial to computer science!